# Hive SQL is giving extraneous input ',' expecting ')' error

Tags: hive, hiveql

My Hive SQL code is as follows:

```
  FROM (
      SELECT *, CONCAT_WS('__', ) AS no_hash_join_key
        FROM xyz.e_6445
       WHERE p_m_id = '{MARKET_ID}'
         AND p_date = '{RUN_DATE_YYYY-MM-DD}'
  ) dataforge
```

I am getting the following error:

```
 extraneous input ',' expecting ')'
```

I am failing to understand what is causing the error. I tried changing it to the following:

```
SELECT *, CONCAT_WS('__', ' ' )
```

This removes the given error but results in a different error :

```
 INSERT_SQL_COLUMN_MISMATCH
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you are missing the second argument for `concat_ws`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a blank parameter in concat_ws. Get rid of the comma (or pass another parameter)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Hive on-hand, but some databases require aliases when using `*` with other columns.  In addition, you need a second argument in `CONCAT_WS()`.

Does this work?

```
SELECT e.*, CONCAT_WS('__', NULL) AS no_hash_join_key
FROM xyz.e_6445 e
WHERE e.p_m_id = '{MARKET_ID}' AND e.p_date = '{RUN_DATE_YYYY-MM-DD}'
```

Comment: SparkSqlParser: Parsing command: with cte as (select item, maker, count(*) as cnt from itemsTable group by item, maker) select t.item,t.maker, CASE WHEN c.cnt = 1 then 'dup_'||c.item else NULL end as dup_values from itemsTable t inner join cte c on t.item = c.item and t.maker = c.maker
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: 
extraneous input 'c' expecting {<EOF>, ',', 'FROM', 'WHERE', 'GROUP', 'ORDER'.......

Comment: after case when it is throwing extraneous input error

Answer (score 0):

My problem was with a CAST function in the Hive SQL:

```
/* this doesn't work: */
CAST((my_date) AS DATE)

/* this one works: */
(CAST(my_date AS DATE))
```